# Vimeo iframe content not showing in ie7

Tags: jquery, vimeo

This has been driving me nuts for days.
I have developed a plugin for the Rapidweaver platform, that makes it easy for a user to have Vimeo videos in a light-box.
I have a problem in testing in IE7. The video content does not get displayed.
You can see a test page here : http://www.garysimpson.co.uk/sandpit/sandpit.html

The plugin has generated the thumbnail from Vimeo and clicking it opens the video in a light-box.
I am testing on a windows xp machine running ie7. All other browsers i have tested in work fine.
Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah IE7...I feel your pain Gary! I had a similar issue on a project recently. There seems to been a problem with embedded content that starts of hidden with `display:none` or similar. The way I got round it was to remove and re-add the video content for IE only when the lightbox was activated. For example:

```
// Check if browser is IE7
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 7){
    // Clone the div containing the video content
    var clone = $("#video-div").clone(true);
    // Remove the div
    $("#video-div").remove();
    // Re-add the div to the lightbox
    $("#lightbox-div").append(clone);
}
```

**EDIT**: You could try using this technique with the legacy embed code, instead of the iframe.

```
<object width="320" height="180">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=7421222&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />
    <embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=7421222&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="320" height="180"></embed>
</object>
```

**FURTHER EDIT**: On doing some testing in Browserstack it looks to be working in IE7 for me. It may be something specific to your test environment. ! [Screen shot of IE7 window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIRCh.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But in my case this does not seem to work. The clone is certainly there, but remains empty re: video content. I even tried just grabbing the html from the original container(vimeo code) and appending that to the light box as the last event in the chain. but it still remains empty in ie7. I could use firebug for ie7 :-)

Comment: Turns out even in a much simplified test. About as simple as it can get... I have just placed the original Vimeo iframe code in a div below on the page and that does not show the content of the iframe either in the ie7 test. Now i am puzzled as i cant find any issues with Vimeo code and ie7 on the net. Yet i cant now even get it to display in ie7 embedded in its simplest form. Test page same as original post.

Comment: Actually @Alchemy it seems to work at the moment for me testing in IE7...maybe it's an issue local to you or your test environment?